# How to return a RACSignal without using [RACSignal createSignal]

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, reactive-cocoa

For example, My current implementation is like below:

```
- (RACSignal *)getPlaylist {
  return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
    [[[buttonClickSignal
      flattenMap:^(UIButton *sender) {
          return [self logInWithUsername:username password:password];
      }]
      flattenMap:^(NSDictionary *json) {
          return [self fetchPlaylistForToken:token];
      }]
      subscribeNext:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        [subscriber sendNext:json];
        [subscriber sendCompleted];
      }];
      return nil;
  }];
}
```

How to return a new signal without using [RACSignal createSignal] method?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just return the mapped `buttonClickSignal`?
I don't see any problems with just this:

```
- (RACSignal *)getPlaylist {
    return [[buttonClickSignal
              flattenMap:^(UIButton *sender) {
                  return [self logInWithUsername:username password:password];
              }]
              flattenMap:^(NSDictionary *json) {
                  return [self fetchPlaylistForToken:token];
              }];
}
```

Since you appear to be ignoring errors right now your current implementation will never actually complete if any of the flattenMapped signals error.